# Plone - How can I use faceted navigation?

Tags: plone, faceted-search

I have a plone site and I have added a content type called game.  There are now several games that have been added and that can be viewed.  I would like to use the eea.facetednavigation module, which you can read about here: http://plone.org/products/eea.facetednavigation.

The idea behind faceted navigation is that one can quickly filter all the objects, which is like doing a search.  For instance, I place all my games in one of about twelve categories according to genre.  I have options like "adventure" "action" "puzzle" "roleplaying" and so on.

I would like to have an area on the side where the user can click "puzzle" and then have the page display only puzzle games.  I would also like to duplicate this behavior elsewhere so the user can filter by price.  Of course if the user filters on both, then that should work as well.

I'm imaginging about four or five different facets that the user can filter on.  Now, I have placed eea.facetednavigation in my buildout.cfg file and when I log in as "admin" I see the option under my Games tab (where I have added some games) to enable faceted navigation.  However, when I do this I get a useless screen that I can't understand and that does not allow me to set up the kind of filtering criteria that I have in mind.  I have attached a screen shot.

As you can see on the screen shot, faceted navigation is giving me options for "video link", "video file", "page", "news item" and so forth.  None of these are the fields associated with my games.  If I cllick "more" on that portal type, I see an option called "games" -- because I have created that content type -- but selecting it doesn't give me the behavior I want.

It is hard to see in the screen shot, but the "Games" tab is highlighted at the top.  That is the folder in which I have enabled faceted navigation, and that is the folder in which I have added several games.

I've tried reading the documentation on faceted navigation -- http://plone.org/products/eea.facetednavigation -- but I've been mulling it over for an hour and I just can't make head nor tail of it.

[image: What my plone faceted navigation configuration screen looks like.]

Comment: Would you mind to give some feedback if you could solve sth/answers helped?

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to solve the problem.

Comment: First of, I admire your honesty, second: thanks for replying! I see, that you headed over to Django, now. If you're still interested in Plone for your project, let us know and we'll be happy to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'price' is an integer-field of your contenttype, you need to enable it as an index in the portal_catalog in order to make it available as a criterion in an eea-searchform.

So, first register the Index in profiles/default/catalog.xml like this:

`<?xml version="1.0"?> <object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">
<index name="Price" meta_type="FieldIndex">   <indexed_attr value="getPrice"/>  </index> </object>`

And then in th eea-searchform add a widget hitting one of the plus-icons, choose f.e. the kind 'Range' and as Index choose 'Price'.

Proceed similar with your other fields, choose checkboxes for your category-widget, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you categorized your games using the standard Plone "Tags" functionality (on the "Categorization" tab if you edit content), then you should be able to simply add a "Select" widget and set it to search the "Tags" index (under "Catalog index to use for search").

I agree that the facetednavigation UI is rather obtuse.

Comment: When I click on the "Games" tab at the top of the page I see the six games I have entered.  I also see a green "admin" toolbar.  I don't see a "Categorization" tab anywhere, however.

Comment: It's part of the default metadata of every piece of Plone content. This is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/UZgZ3

Note that my answer applies to searching by tags --- not to searching by content type. For that, see Ida Ebkes's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a widget of type "Checkboxes" and choose "Subject" from Catalog Index and choose "Yes" on "Catalog Get unique values from catalog as an alternative for vocabulary". This should gives you a list of checkboxes with the categories. Also add an hidden (you can hide it clicking on the eye icon) widget selected on the "games" type, so results are pre-filtered on that content types so "Subject" widget contains only the games category and not all from the site.

For the prize, follow the Ida answer.